# Any library for a component like this in Angular 8/9

Tags: angular

today im searching a help to find a component library for angular 8/9 like the picture of example below, im using right now this library for date pick https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/, but i need something like the image.

[Date picker example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3svK.png)

any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: [Visit](https://ng.ant.design/components/date-picker/en). If you have no constraint about using any  `front-end` library . Check link and have a look at  `dates` with  `time`.

Comment: wow thanks this is what i was looking for

Comment: Fine , I've added it in answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visit](https://ng.ant.design/components/date-picker/en). If you have no constraint about using any `front-end` library . Check link and have a look at `dates` with `time`.